# Combine rows to a column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a question about combining rows to a column in Google Spreadsheets. There are a lot of threads already about this topic, but I couldn't find one about this particular problem.

This is the data I have at the moment.

- Name1 Name_1_belonging_to_1 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_1
- Name2 Name_1_belonging_to_2 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_2
- Name3 Name_1_belonging_to_3 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_3

What I need is:

- 1 Name1
- 2 Name_1_belonging_to_1
- 3 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_1
- 4 Name2
- 5 Name_1_belonging_to_2
- 6 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_2
- 7 Name3
- 8 Name_1_belonging_to_3
- 9 Name_2_belonging_to_Name_3

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using split, join and transpose and just adjust your range to include the actual number of rows:

```
=transpose(split(join(" ",A2:A3)," "))
```

[image]